# JavaFX сделать доступным инстанс MainXMLController в других котроллерах?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть три контроллера ***CategoryListController***, ***DrawerContentController***, ***PopupContentController***; И есть еще главный контроллер ***MainXMLController*** каждый контроллер использует свой fxml файл для отрисовки но для всех контроллеров нужен инстанс ***MainXMLController'a*** 
Сейчас у меня в каждом контроллер есть такой метод ***getMainController***

```
public MainXMLController getMainController(){ 

       FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/main.fxml"));

       return (MainXMLController) fxmlLoader.getController(); }
```

Создал ***BaseController*** в него перенес метод ***getMainController*** и все три контроллера теперь наследуются с ***BaseController*** но когда вызываю *getMainController* например с  *CategoryListController* получаю ***NullPointer***. Что не так ?

```
public class BaseController {

    protected MainXMLController mainXMLController;

    public MainXMLController getMainXMLController() {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/main.xml.fxml"));

        return fxmlLoader.getController();

    }
```

}

```
public class CategoryListController extends BaseController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private JFXListView<CategoryModel> categoryList;

private CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    renderCategoryList(categoryModel.getAllCategory());
    setEventListnerListvView();
}

private void setEventListnerListvView(){
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = mouseEvent -> {

        CategoryModel selectedItem = categoryList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            System.out.println("id = " + selectedItem.getId());
            //initMainController();
            if(getMainController() != null){
                getMainController().setTypeItText(selectedItem.getCategoryName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Ctrl is null");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("no item selected");
        }
    };
    categoryList.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, handler);

}

private void renderCategoryList(ResultSet resultSet){

    categoryList.setCellFactory(lv -> new LVCellViewHolder<>(){
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(CategoryModel item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(empty || item == null ? "" : item.getCategoryName());
        }
    });

    ObservableList categoryListRow = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            categoryListRow.add(new CategoryModel(resultSet.getInt("id"), resultSet.getString("category_name")));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    categoryList.setItems(categoryListRow);
}

public Node getView(){
    return categoryList;
}
```

}

Comment: "Создал BaseController в него перенес метод getMainController и все три контроллера"
Покажите код.

Comment: Дабвил код BaseController CategoryLIstController

Comment: Получить контроллер из `fxmlLoader` можно после вызова метода `load()`. Вы ведь понимаете, что у вас будет 4 разных экземпляра `MainXMLController`?

Comment: Можно любым доступным способом внедрить MainXMLController в остальные контроллеры: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1048237/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be/1048857#1048857