# Не получается передать данные контроллера из первого окна в контроллер второго окна

Tags: java, javafx

**Фрагмент контроллера первого окна:**

```
nextButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            Human human = new Human(Float.parseFloat(fieldHeight.getText()), Float.parseFloat(fieldWeight.getText()),
                    Integer.parseInt(fieldAge.getText()), fieldName.getText(), "Male", Integer.parseInt(fieldPass.getText()), fieldLogin.getText());

            ...

            nextButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(heightAndWeightController.class.getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
            try {
                loader.load();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Parent root = loader.getRoot();

            Controller controller = loader.getController();
            controller.transferUser(human);

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.setTitle("Weight Contoller");
            stage.show();
            stage.setResizable(false);
        });
    }
```

**Контроллер второго окна:**

```
package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import Database.DBHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller {
    public Object select = null;
    public Human human = new Human();
    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Label currentHaWLable;

    @FXML
    private Label fieldCcal;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        System.out.println(human.getName());


    }

    public void transferUser(Human _human){
        human.setName(_human.getName());
        human.setAge(_human.getAge());
        human.setWeight(_human.getWeight());
        human.setHeight(_human.getHeight());
        human.setCcal(_human.getCcal());
        human.setLogin(_human.getLogin());
        human.setPassword(_human.getPassword());
        human.setGender(_human.getGender());
    }
}
```

Почему не вызывается метод transferUser для второго окна в контроллере первого?

Comment: А каким образом вы хотите передавать данные между окнами? Вы написали два класса, которые находятся в одном проекте? Ну так они и будут внутри одной программы передавать данные. Данные между двумя программами можно передать с помощью сокетов.

Comment: @AndreyM при открытии второго окна объекту класса Human во втором окне не присваиваются значения полей, которые я передаю в методе transferUser в первом окне. Поля объекта класса Human во втором окне остаются по-умолчанию.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия сокеты мне не подходят, я передаю данные не между двумя программами, а между двумя разными окнами внутри одной программы при помощи getController(), но я не знаю, почему метод transferUser, который я описал во втором контроллере, не устанавливает поля для обьекта класса Human

Comment: На первый взгляд все выглядит правильно. А проверяете, что человек передался случайно не по строчке `System.out.println(human.getName());`? Потому что она вызывается раньше, чем дергается метод `transferUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов, как передать данные из одного FXML контроллера в другой достаточно много. Вкратце рассмотрим некоторые из них, начиная с рекомендуемого подхода.

- В случае небольших приложений лучше передавать данные напрямую, это
  просто и не требует дополнительных расходов.
- Для больших приложений следует сразу задуматься о внедрении
  зависимостей или шине событий (event bus).

Первый случай.

**Передача данных напрямую.**

С помощью FXML-загрузчика получаем ссылку на второй контроллер, и вызываем его метод. Просто и доступно:

```
public Stage showCustomerDialog(Customer customer) {
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
    getClass().getResource(
      "customerDialog.fxml"
    )
  );

  Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
  stage.setScene(
    new Scene(
      (Pane) loader.load()
    )
  );

  CustomerDialogController controller = 
    loader.getController();
  controller.initData(customer);

  stage.show();

  return stage;
}

...

class CustomerDialogController {
  @FXML private Label customerName;
  void initialize() {}
  void initData(Customer customer) {
    customerName.setText(customer.getName());
  }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что создаётся именно новый FXMLLoader: **new FXMLLoader(location)**.

Не пытайтесь использовать статический метод загрузки **FXMLLoader.load(…)**. Таким способом получить контроллер от экземпляра загрузчика не удастся!

Ещё раз по шагам:

1. На основе FXML файла создать FXMLLoader.
2. Получить у экземпляра FXMLLoader контроллер.
3. Путём вызова метода полученного контроллера передать ему нужные данные.

*Если захочется этот подход унифицировать, то идею можно развить. Например, второй контроллер, и последующие могут реализовывать какой-либо интерфейс с методом init(Object object). После получения контроллера вызывается этот метод инициализации.*

**Установка контроллера в FXMLLoader.**

Другое решение – создание второго контроллера вручную. В этом случае все необходимые параметры можно передать напрямую в его конструктор. Остаётся только передать этот контроллер FXML-загрузчику:

```
CustomerDialogController dialogController = 
    new CustomerDialogController(param1, param2);

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
    getClass().getResource(
        "customerDialog.fxml"
    )
);
loader.setController(dialogController);

Pane mainPane = (Pane) loader.load();
```

Тут есть моменты. Если JavaFX старый (например 2-й версии), то в FXML файле не следует определять атрибут fx:controller.

**Получение данных из статического источника.**

В этом случае в каком-либо классе, например, даже в первом контроллере, заводим статическую переменную или статический метод, и из второго контроллера обращаемся к ним.

*Просто, дёшево и сердито. Почему бы не делать только так? Да потому что статические переменные хранят глобальное состояние. То есть, их могут менять все, кому этого захочется, и можно получить трудно отслеживаемые баги, особенно если приложение большое. Кроме того, статические данные сильно мешают тестированию, поскольку не удаётся изолировать каждый случай.*

Для маленьких домашних проектов это наипростейшее решение. Сам периодически этим грешу. Правда, статические данные всё же лучше держать в отдельном классе.

**Внедрение зависимостей.**

Если проект планируется большим, или не хочется заморачиваться со связыванием кучи классов вручную (а в случае JavaFX это актуально), то надо задуматься над внедрением зависимостей.

Это обширная тема для обсуждения. Если вкратце, то FXMLLoader уже из коробки имеет поддержку систем для внедрения зависимостей, таких как Spring, Java EE CDI или Google Guice. В загрузчик можно передать стороннюю фабрику контроллеров. Как результат, появляется возможность создавать контроллеры и автоматически внедрять в них любые зависимости. Единственное неудобство – порядок загрузки контроллеров. Лечится аннотацией @Lazy, а так же использованием MVC модели. То есть, лучше внедрять в контроллеры сервисы а не другие контроллеры.

Пример такой реализации JavaFX + String Boot + Maven: https://github.com/LeonisX/rom-shingler

**Шина данных**

Это ещё одно решение для больших производственных приложений.

Грег Браун, автор спецификации FXML частенько советует налаживать общение между FXML контроллерами и другими частями системы с помощью шину данных, например, Guava EventBus. Это простой в использовании API для публикации/подписки, позволяющий с помощью аннотаций наладить общение различных POJO между собой, без их жёсткой привязки. Сам я пока до такого не дорос, но на перспективу - это должно быть отличным решением отвязки от Спринга.

Взято отсюда: http://javatut.tv-games.ru/page/javafx-controllers-interaction

Answer (score 0):

Тоже когда-то замучился с передачей данных из одного контроллера в другой. Задача была сделать доступным Мейнкотроллер для всех остальных контроллеров. Решил использовать статический метод, потому что статик метод инициализируется при первом обращении к классу.

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static MainXMLController mainXMLController;

    public static MainXMLController getMainController() {
        // System.out.println(mainXMLController);
        return mainXMLController;
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {

            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/main.xml.fxml"));

            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

            mainXMLController = fxmlLoader.getController();
            //mainXMLController.setMainController(mainXMLController);
            mainXMLController.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```